# java method overload share same memory or different memory for different nethod

Tags: java, multithreading, memory, overloading

In java if I overload methods as shown below

```
public void test (int a,int b)
public int test(String str)
public boolean test (float a)
```

Then all of the above methods  will use same memory or different for each test.
If they share same memory location then how it will work in multi threading environment.

Thanks

Comment: They are three completely separate methods -- just as separate as if they had different names.

Answer (score 2):

There is no memory being allocated for a method *per se*. Memory is allocated:

- For a class - one shared allocation for all `static` members (once per classloader, to be precise)
- For an instance - for its instance / non-static members
- For method invocation - each invocation will allocate a separate stack frame for its parameters etc.
- For local variables - no sharing here either